# The exponential matrix of system of ODEs, is a fundamental matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following system of differential equations:
$$
\mathbf{\dot{x}} = A\mathbf{x}
$$
Imagine you have the solutions: $\{ \mathbf{x_1}, \mathbf{x_2}, \; \dots \;, \mathbf{x_n}\}$. The general solution of the system is:
$$
\mathbf{x}(t) = C_1\mathbf{x_1} + C_2\mathbf{x_2} + \; \dots \; + C_n\mathbf{x_n}\
$$
The fundamental matrix of the system is:
$$
\Phi(t) = \left (\mathbf{x_1} \;\;  \mathbf{x_2} \;\; ... \;\; \mathbf{x_n} \right)
$$
So $\mathbf x$, could be written as:
$$
\mathbf x(t)  = \Phi(t) \mathbf c 
$$
where $\mathbf c = (C_1 \;\; C_2 \;\; \dots \;\; C_n)^T$.

But, if we solve the system like this:
$$
\mathbf{\dot{x}} = A\mathbf{x} \\ \; \\
\mathbf x(t) = e^{At}\mathbf{x_0} = x_1(0)\mathbf{x_1} + x_2(0)\mathbf{x_2} + \; \dots \; + x_n(0)\mathbf{x_n}
$$
Then by this line of reasoning, $e^{At}$ is a fundamental matrix of the system. But $\mathbf c \neq \mathbf x_0$. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In the second half of your question, you've assumed that $x_i(t)$ are the solutions corresponding to the initial condition where the ith coordinate is $1$ and all others are zero; see this by computing $x(0)$ on the left hand side and comparing. This is probably what you did when computing the fundamental matrix $\Phi(t)$ and, in that case, $\Phi(0) = I$ so $c = x_0$ and there is no inconsistency.

Note the fundamental matrix is clearly not unique (you can pick any linearly independent solution set...) unless you impose some additional conditions such as what $\Phi(0)$ looks like. If you start with some arbitrary linearly independent solutions, it may be the case that $\Phi(0) \neq I$ in which case there is again no inconsistency since in that case $x_0$ does not appear multiplying $\Phi(t)$ anyway. It would be the case that $c = \Phi(0)^{-1} x_0$.